# Iterate over lists inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

Is there any way to iterate over lists inside a dictionary.
A key inside dictionary contains a list which needs to be iterated over separately from the other lists. When I try to iterate over the dictionary, it iterates over the 0th element of each key.value instead of iterating over one list.

as an example, the dictionary below should be iterated.
First the iteration should be able to access the list inside 'a' separately and the list inside 'b'.

```
d = {'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2,2,2,2]}
```

Comment: What have you tried for this?

Comment: I have tried using nested loops but it gives me an error. The nested loops work for when the dictionary contains a single value. The only other workaround I know how to do is to convert the dictionary into a list of dictionaries and then iterate over them. I wanted to know a better way to go about this.

Comment: Add it in the question for more clarity

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I need each list to be computed through a function to calculate values. So 'a' is one variable and 'b' is another. They need to be separated and passed through a function.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate in the lists inside the dictionary you can try something like this,

```
d = {'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2,2,2,2]}

for key in d:
  for item in d[key]:
    print(item) #Change this line to whatever you want to do
```

To iterate only on `a` do,

```
for item in d["a"]:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thankyou. But is there a way to iterate over only 'a' in this scenario and exclude the iteration of 'b'

Comment: `for i in d['a']: ...`

Comment: Note also that instead of `for key in d: for item in d[key]: ...` you can do `for v in d.values(): for item in v:`

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2,2,2,2]}

for k,v in d.items():
  for item in d[k]:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension like so:

```
[print(num) for lst in d.values() for num in lst]
```

The list is not saved at the end.

Comment: Yes it will be garbage collected after, but meanwhile when the list comp is being executed, your script holds a list of unnecessary `None`s.

Answer (score 0):

Using `from_iterable` :

```
import itertools

d = {'a' : [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2,2,2,2]}

for key, value in (
        itertools.chain.from_iterable((itertools.product((k,), v) for k, v in d.items()))):
        
        if(key=='a'):
            print(value)
```